# How do I perform MAX(COUNT(*)) query?

Tags: sql-server, database, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have a database where I have MenuItem, Item, Item_Details, and Item_Category tables. I would like to get an Item which is most frequently used in Menu.

```
SELECT 
  ItemName, 
  Category, 
  ItemPrice
FROM 
  restuarant.Menu_Item, 
  restuarant.Item, 
  restuarant.Item_Details, 
  restuarant.Item_Type
WHERE ItemId = Id_Item 
AND ItemTypeId = Id_ItemType 
AND ItemDetailsId = Id_ItemDetails 
AND ItemId = 
  (SELECT ItemId                                                                     
     FROM restuarant.Menu_Item
     HAVING COUNT(ItemId) = 
       (SELECT MAX(COUNT(ItemId))
        FROM restuarant.Menu_Item
        GROUP BY Id_MenuItem);
```

So the problems is I'm performing my subqueries incorrectly, I'm getting an error 'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.'

Comment: The editor has a code format button, please use it to format your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
SELECT TOP (1) ItemId,  COUNT(ItemId) AS MCOUNT
FROM            Menu_Item
GROUP BY ItemId
ORDER BY  COUNT(ItemId) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Example 1:

```
select aic.County, count(*) from Address_Information_County aic
group by aic.County
having count(*) = (select top 1 count(*) from Address_Information_County group by County order by count(*) desc);
```

Example 2:

```
select aic.County, count(*) from Address_Information_County aic
group by aic.County
having count(*) = (select max(cnt) from (select count(*) cnt from Address_Information_County group by County) x);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use "Group By" aggregate function to achieve this.

```
SELECT ItemID, count(*) as cnt
FROM restaurant r
GROUP BY r.ItemID
ORDER BY cnt desc
LIMIT 1;
```

In case, there are multiple entries that have count same as MaxCount, the following query would work.

```
SELECT ItemID, count(*) as cnt
FROM restaurant r
GROUP BY r.ItemID
HAVING count(*) = 
(
SELECT count(*) as max_cnt
FROM restaurant r2
GROUP BY r2.ItemID
ORDER BY max_cnt desc
LIMIT 1
)
;
```

Comment: In this case if I have more than 1 record on this query it just drops others..

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question, "I use ..." isn't an answer which doesn't help the OP or others.

Comment: Actually, in PL/SQL you can use: SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)), but in T/SQL it gives an error: 'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.'